# Parse error in a case statement

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, type-conversion, parse-error, option-type

I am trying to convert a Maybe Int to an Int in Haskell like this:

```
convert :: Maybe Int -> Int
convert mx = case mx of 
               Just x -> x
              Nothing -> error "error message"
```

When I compile it, Haskell tells me: `parse error on input 'Nothing'`.

I need this, because I want to get the Index of an element in a list with the elem.Index function from the Data.List module and then use this index on the take function. My problem is that `elemIndex` returns a `Maybe Int`, but `take` needs an `Int`.

Comment: I hope you understand that “converting” this way is not really a clever idea: you're essentially subverting the type system. Only do this when you're absolutely sure that the argument is a `Just`, but the type checker can't proove it. And even then it's better to explicitly match `case mx of {Just x -> x}` right where you need it, not through a helper function. The reason being: if this match _does_ fail, it will give you a nice clear error message telling where it happened. Your `convert` will always give you the same error message when the assumption fails, no matter where you use it.

Comment: It sounds like you just need `takeWhile (/= item)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a whitespace problem. The `case` clauses need to be indented to the same level.

```
convert :: Maybe Int -> Int
convert mx = case mx of 
               Just x -> x
               Nothing -> error "error message"
```

Remember to use only spaces, no tabs.

Comment: That said, what the OP seems to want, is [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust).

Comment: @bereal: mhhhh... I wouldn't recommend `fromJust`. See my comment above to the question. (It's still better than `convert`, though.)

Answer (score 2):

To add to @leftaroundabout's answer, I think I might provide you with some other options.

First off, you shouldn't make unsafe things like this: your program will fail. It's much cleaner to keep it as a `Maybe Int` and operate as such, safely. In other words, this was a simple parse error, but making incomplete functions like this may cause far greater problems in the future.

The problem you've encountered it, *how can I do that?*

We might make a better function, like this:

```
mapMaybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
mapMaybe f m = case m of
     Just a  -> f a
     Nothing -> Nothing
```

Which would allow you to write:

```
λ> (+ 15) `mapMaybe` Just 9
Just 24
```

However, there is a function called `fmap`, which 'maps' a function over certain data-structures, `Maybe` included:

```
λ> (== 32) `fmap` Just 9
Just False
```

and if you have `import`ed `Control.Applicative`, there is a nice operator synonym for it:

```
λ> show <$> Just 9
Just "9"
```

If you want to know more about these data-structures, called Functors, I would recommend reading [Learn-you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).